# How to create CloudKit subscription notification to fire on record attribute update?

Tags: ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification, cloudkit, cksubscription

I use CloudKit. I have a `Channel` record type which does have `isLive` as an attribute. It can be either `0` or `1` indicating if the channel is live.

I want to send a notification to all users if the live status if a channel changes from 0 to 1.

I tried to define the CKQuerySubscription like this:

```
    let liveSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Channel", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "(recordID == '4cebe441-c6f7-47af-85df-e6572e757c5c') AND (isLive == 1)"), options: [.firesOnRecordUpdate])
    let liveNotificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
    liveNotificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = false
    liveNotificationInfo.shouldBadge = true
    liveNotificationInfo.alertBody = "Test is live now"
    channelSubscription.notificationInfo = liveNotificationInfo
```

This does send a notification on any update of this channel record though. It does not care about the `isLive` predicate.

Any idea how can I receive notifications only for `isLive` change from 0 to 1?

Or is it better to receive all updates on this channel record, process them in my app and then send a local notification if necessary?

Comment: hi got any workaround? it also not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to register for changes only on one attribute update. You will get the notification always when **ANY** of fields is updated. This is much better and it works always like this.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First, you should be sending a reference to the record rather than the raw recordName string. Second, add `.firesOnce` to the subscription so it only fires once.

```
            let reference = CKReference(recordID: recordID, action: .none)
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@ && %K == %@",
                                        "isLive", 1,
                                        "recordID", reference)
            let liveSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Channel",
                                                       predicate: predicate,
                                                       options: [.firesOnRecordUpdate, .firesOnce])
```